# Inductive proof of kth falling power

Tags: combinatorics, alternative-proof

I have been trying to prove the kth falling power

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{\underline{n-k}}y^{\underline{k}}= (x+y)^{\underline{n}}
$$

However I can only prove it using a combinatorial proof. Really appreciate if someone could provide a inductive proof

Comment: More or less duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1271688) (see the second solution)