# Binomial expansion with mixed exponential and falling factorial terms

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

Is there a way to simplify the sum
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m} \underbrace{q(q-1)\dots(q-k+m+1)}_{k-m\text{ terms}}(-1)^{k-m} (q-1)^m,
\end{align*}

where $q$ is sufficiently large? It clearly resembles the binomial expansion, as well as [this falling factorial version of it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271688/combinatorial-proof-of-falling-factorial-and-binomial-theorem), but it is different from both.

If there is no easy way to simplify it, a good upper bound, or a characterization of scaling behavior with $q$ would also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

*I am not sure that this would help much.*

Let $$a_m=(-1)^{k-m}\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-m-1}(q-i)\right)\binom{k}{m}(q-1)^m=-q (q-1)^m \binom{k}{m} (1-q)_{k-m-1}$$ where appears Pochhammer symbol $$\sum_{m=0}^ka_m=\frac{ \Gamma (k-q)}{\Gamma (-q)}\, _1F_1(-k;-k+q+1;q-1)$$where appears  Kummer confluent hypergeometric function.